# Dynamic HTML container between header and footer

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I would like to transform my html structure and css that the navigations height is always enlarging dynamicly acording to the height of content. A short explanation will be: There should not be any gap between footer and the green navigation on the left.

http://letpack.lukasoppler.ch/

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that you are having an issue with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use javascript for dynamically getting the height of right section and then assign the same height to your green navigation on the left.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var h = $('.content').height();
  $('ul#nav').height(h + 18)
});
```

The above code will work in your page

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```js
$(function(){

 setHeight();
  
 $(window).resize(function(){
   setHeight();
  });
 
  function setHeight(){
   $("#nav").css("min-height", $(".content").height());
  }
});
```

```css
.img{height: 50px;width: 100%;background: blue;}
#nav{width: 25%;float: left;background: red;height: 100%;}
.content{width: 75%;float: left;}
.footer{background: green;clear: both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="img">

</div>
<div id="nav">

In unserem Betrieb leben wir gemeinsame Werte, denn wir stellen den Menschen und seine 
</div>
<div class="content">
Willkommen
Wir sind eine Organisation, die Menschen mit einer psychischen Erkrankung beschäftigt und begleitet.
Entwicklungen in den Mittelpunkt und wachsen gemeinsam.

Aktuell
Ab dem 29. Oktober bis 15. November 2016 verkaufen wir unsere kunsthandwerklichen Produkte auf dem Petersplatz. Wir freuen uns auf Ihren Besuch!

Betriebsferien:
Vom 23. Dezember 2016 bis 1. Januar 2017 ist unsere Institution geschlossen.

</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
footer content
</div>
```

Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/mv72L22g/